# Cocos3d: Crashing when loading scene in separate thread or background thread:

Tags: cocos3d

I am trying to load several big models in code and show the scenes. Generally, it is taking long time for loading and showing scene on screen as it need to extract lot of resources from a pod model.
So, i thought of populate the first scene in main thread and remaining others in a separate thread. But, it is crashing when i move my part code into separate thread. Here is my sample code:

```
    -(void) loadFirstScene
{
CC3PODResourceNode* podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"FirstModel"];
podRezNode.resource = [IntroducingPODResource resourceFromFile: @"FirstModel.pod"];
podRezNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
podRezNode.location = cc3v(0.0, -10.0, 0.2);
podRezNode.isTouchEnabled = YES;
[self addChild: podRezNode];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadScenesInThread) toTarget:self
withObject:nil];
}

// Crashing if i add the below function in separate thread or background thread
-(void) loadScenesInThread
{
CC3PODResourceNode* podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"SecondModel"];
podRezNode.resource = [IntroducingPODResource resourceFromFile: @"SecondModel.pod"];

podRezNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
podRezNode.location = cc3v(0.0, -10.0, -5.0);
podRezNode.isTouchEnabled = YES;
[self addChild: podRezNode];

podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"ThirdModel"];
podRezNode.resource = [IntroducingPODResource resourceFromFile: @"ThirdModel.pod"];

podRezNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
podRezNode.location = cc3v(0.0, -10.0, -5.0);
podRezNode.isTouchEnabled = YES;
[self addChild: podRezNode];

// .. do more
}
```

Could someone guide me how would i handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can not create or access OpenGL resources in a thread that's different from the thread the OpenGL context was created on. Your only option is to use any "async" method cocos2d offers, or example for loading textures.

Comment: Can you please point me out where i can see sample for "async" method?

Comment: check CCTextureCache in api ref. No idea if cocos3d offers such methods.